# How to convert sum into formula?

Tags: summation

I am reading some combinatorics books. And here author first obtained a sum answer for a problem and then converted it to formula without explaining it. Just writing equality sign. This is that expression:
$$2(2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k(k-1) + n(n-1)) = 2(\frac{1}{3}(n-1)n(2n-1)-n(n-1)+n(n-1)) = \frac{2}{3}n(n-1)(2n-1)$$

The main question is "**How did he get this?**". I often face with this problem where I need to convert such sums into formula. And additionally, I'll really appreciate if you show some technics to do this.

Comment: This is named "getting the closed form" of some expressions. For the case you show here you can apply different methods: algebraic manipulation of partial sums, the use of generating or the use of the rules of the beautiful [finite calculus](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dgleich/publications/Gleich%202005%20-%20finite%20calculus.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be familiar with [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula), not to memorize but to know it exists and where to look it up.  Then $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k(k-1)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^2-k\\=\frac 16(n-1)n(2n-1)-\frac 12(n-1)n$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it. Is there any book or reference only about this stuff? Like converying sums into formulas, and working with sum

Answer (score 3):

The basic formulas used here are

$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}
$

and
$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$.

There are similar formulas
for higher powers.

Answer (score 2):

Discrete sums work just like integrals, but you have to replace powers by falling powers: 
$$
k^{\underline{n}} \equiv k\cdot (k-1) \cdot (k-2) \cdots (k-n+1)
$$
with $n$ factors just like $k^n$, but they are falling.  Thus for example $k^{\underline{k}} = k!$.
When you have a sum of falling powers, the formula is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n k^{\underline{n}} = \frac{1}{n+1} k^{\underline{n+1}}
$$
(see that is just like integrating $x^n$).

Using this tecnique, the problem you have becomes easy.

Comment: I have to admit, it never occured to me to related sums like this to integration, but of course there are similarities is integration *is* just sums over teeny intervals.  This will save me lots of time in the future as I can never remember any sum but the single powers.

Comment: I've never met such thing. Could you please share some reference or book about this subject?

Comment: Concrete Mathematics, by Graham, Knuth and Patashkin, has excellent material on this and other related subjects.